# Protect A Specific Sheet Button?

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a button that allows my boss to remove 1 of the many sheets in a workbook **based on his input of the sheet name**. This Remove Sheet button is password protected since other people use the workbook I wouldn't want them to delete anything.

Now this does not prevent them from right clicking the specific sheet and deleting, so I need a way to PROTECT all the sheets when the Remove Sheet Button is not pressed, and UNPROTECT all sheets once the password for that button is inputted correctly, **since the button cannot remove a sheet that is protected**.

Remove Sheet Button Code:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim delSheet As String
Dim response As String
Dim SheetFound As Boolean
Dim MyPass As String
Dim MyPasswrd As String, answ As String

 MyPasswrd = "test"                                                             'password verification puts trigger in cell A100, an deletes when file close
 If Range("A101").Value <> "OK" Then
     answ = InputBox("Please Enter The Password To Continue.", "Enter Password")
        If answ <> MyPasswrd Then
             MsgBox "Incorrect Password!", vbExclamation, "Warning"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Range("A101").Value = "OK"
End If

delSheet = InputBox("Please Enter The LAST NAME Of The DTS You Want To Remove", "Remove A DTS")                     'user input

If delSheet = "" Then
MsgBox "You Did Not Complete The Entry.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Warning"                       'if NULL input displays this message
Exit Sub

Else
  If IsLetter(delSheet) = False Then GoTo Display                                                   'checks the user input

response = MsgBox("WARNING!! This Action Cannot Be Undone, Do You Still Want To Continue?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Warning")     'verfies user input


If response = vbYes Then                                                                'if input is yes  selects sheet IF ITS FOUND
On Error Resume Next

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(delSheet).Select
        If Err = 0 Then SheetFound = True                                               'searches for sheet

    On Error GoTo 0

    If SheetFound = False Then                                                      'if sheet not found displays this message

        MsgBox prompt:="The sheet '" & delSheet & "' Could Not Be Found In This File!", Buttons:=vbExclamation, Title:="Search Result"
        Exit Sub

    Else

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False                                                  'Finally deletes sheet and bypass xcel warning for sheet deletion
 Sheets(delSheet).Delete
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox ("The DTS " & delSheet & " Was Successfully Removed")                                    'message for sucessfully deleting the sheet
Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("Control Center").Range("B1"), Scroll:=True
End If

Else

response = vbNo                                                                         'if user does not want to delete sheet exits window
Exit Sub

Display:
     MsgBox "Invalid Character In Last Name. Please Only Use Letters And Numbers(1-9), NOT Spaces and Specail Characters (! @ # $ % ^ & * - + = \ _ .)", vbExclamation, "Warning"

End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sheet deletion can't be stopped, at least not without  a lot of code / structure protection. But before save of the workbook you can always determine the sheet presence and if it's not there then you prevent the workbook from being saved. This is the easiest and simplest route.

Comment: I did some research and found this [Delete A protected sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645870/prevent-user-from-deleting-a-particular-sheet) but I dont know how to implement this in my code. Basically you create a control sheet with all the sheet names, then when you click on a sheet in the control it runs a macro to UNPROTECT all the sheets so that it be deleted, then the sheets in the workbook goes back to being PROTECTED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **Excel-2013 or Excel-2016** then, you can use `Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete` event. 
In the workbook module add this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public IsPasswordOK  As Boolean
Public IsDeleteOK    As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not IsDeleteOK Then
        MsgBox "You deleted a sheet without permission. Can't save the file."
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    IsDeleteOK = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If IsDeleteOK Then
        IsDeleteOK = IsPasswordOK
    End If
End Sub
```

---

In your `CommandButton4_Click()` code after the line `Sheets(delSheet).Delete` add this line

```
ThisWorkbook.IsPasswordOK=True
```

---

For version prior to **Excel-2013**

First add a module name it `mdlSheetWatch`. Add following code in that module.

```
Option Explicit

Public IsPasswordOK  As Boolean
Public dctSheets
Public Function IsSheetsOk()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lCtr    As Long
    Dim bResult As Boolean

    If IsPasswordOK Then
        bResult = True
        Exit Function
    Else

       bResult = True
        For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
           If Not dctSheets.exists(wks.CodeName) Then
            bResult = False
            Exit For
           End If
        Next

    End If

    IsSheetsOk = bResult

End Function

Public Function LoadSheetList() As Object
     Dim wks As Worksheet
     Dim dctTemp As Object

     Set dctTemp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

      For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        dctTemp.Add wks.CodeName, wks.Name
      Next

    Set LoadSheetList = dctTemp

End Function
```

---

Now in the workbook module,  add following code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not mdlSheetWatch.IsSheetsOk Then
        MsgBox "You deleted/renamed a sheet without permission. Can't save the file."
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Set dctSheets = mdlSheetWatch.LoadSheetList
End Sub
```

---

Lastly, in your `CommandButton4_Click()` code after the line
`Sheets(delSheet).Delete`
add this line

`mdlSheetWatch.IsPasswordOK=True`

---

This should prevent users without password to save the workbook after deleting/renaming/adding a sheet.

Comment: When you say users without passwords do you mean in order to open the workbook they need a password?

Comment: no i mean somebody who doesn't have YOUR password "test"  to delete the sheet. How it will work. First store  list of sheets.  second when sheet is deleted by your code, store a flag to skip any check. third when the file is being saved, it will check (skip this if flag is true) if the current list of worksheets match with actual worksheets. If yes allow save. if no don't allow save.

Comment: In "SheetBeforeDelete" I'd also inform the user that since bla bla the workbook will not be saved, so as not to have it working on it in vain (maybe for hours!)

Comment: why the downvote? Is something wrong with the code? Plz point out.

Comment: I used the 2013 excel code, but for some reason, if I copy a sheet thats already there to make a new sheet. Then rename that copied sheet an I try to delete it using my Remove sheet button, it deletes BUT, I  am unable to save my workbook because it thinks I deleted it without permission???

Comment: If I add a sheet the normal way and delete it using the button everything works fine, its just sometimes I might want to copy a previous sheet and rename to put different info inside it, and if I cant check if these types of sheets are deleted then there is an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Event `BeforeDelete` of the Worksheet class does not have a `Cancel` option, but this a workaround to perform the cancel operation.

1- In a normal module, put this routine:

```
Sub unprotectThis()
    ThisWorkbook.unprotect
End Sub
```

2- In the code module of the worksheet that you want to protect from deletion, add this event handler:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDelete()
    ThisWorkbook.Protect
    MsgBox "This sheet can be deleted only by the administrator through the dedicated button", vbExclamation
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "unprotectThis"
End Sub
```

We have somehow *"simulated"* the Cancel option. One second later the workbook will be unprotected again.

3- Finally, in the button's handler, where you ask for password, just disable events before actually performing the delete. This will not call the above Worksheet_BeforeDelete handler. Restore events back before leaving:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    On Error goto RestoreEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = false
    ...
    ' your routine that checks for password and performs the delete...
    ...
RestoreEvents:
    Application.EnableEvents = true
End Sub
```

Notice that this solution does not even require to protect the workbook, it only protects a given worksheet.

Comment: So it protects 1 sheet/whichever sheet is trying to be deleted at a given time, if the user HAS NOT pressed the Remove sheet button? Nice.

Comment: @Deathkamp Exactly. You can apply this protecction technique to any individual sheet and you dont need to protect the workbook :)