# Excel AddIn: How to detect/prevent an Excel user from removing a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2013
- MS Office 2013
- C#

I just discovered the **SheetBeforeDelete** event which is very helpful for my application's requirements.

It seems, however, that all the programmer can expect is to be notified about the impending, inevitable disappearance of a worksheet.

What if we need to programmatically implement a policy whereby the removal of certain worksheet(s) is verboten? Is there a way to instruct Excel "Abort the ongoing operation"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent user from deleting a particular sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645870/prevent-user-from-deleting-a-particular-sheet)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. There are new events available since 2013 and my language is C#

Comment: C# and VB use the same framework, which is .NET. All classes and methods are similar. Usually, there should be a `Cancel` argument that you could set in the event method, but it doesn't seem to be available for this case.

Comment: There is a similar situation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbook-beforesave-event-excel I wonder whether it is possible to have a dialog box that returns "Cancel" in case the user decides not to proceed with the sheet removal?

Comment: For instance, the equivalent C# handler for BeforeSave has a cancel argument: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbookevents_beforesaveeventhandler.aspx, but the one for BeforeDelete doesn't: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbookevents_sheetbeforedeleteeventhandler.aspx ----- If you're lucky, you may find in the worksheet object a property such as `CanDelete`, but I'm not positive about that.

Comment: Daniel: The closest I found to "CanDelete" is "Protection", "ProtectionMode" and "ProtectScenarios"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best what you can do is to use the [Protect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm175156)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) method of the `Worksheet` or `Workbook` class which allows to protect a worksheet so that it cannot be modified.