# VBA - protect excel sheet from deletion

Tags: vba, excel, password-protection

I have written the following VBA code for protection of a specific sheet.

```
ActiveSheet.Protect ("password"), DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

It is successful in protecting the sheet from any kind of editing.
But still I am able to delete the complete sheet.

How can I make my sheet protected from deletion?

Comment: `ActiveSheet` is just whatever worksheet happens to be active when that instruction runs, not *a specific sheet*. Why the parentheses around `"password"`?

Comment: Worksheet protection protects the formatting and accessibility of a sheet - not its existence. You need to configure *workbook protection* to protect the *workbook's structure*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32156468/1188513).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for the prompt response. Got it.